# How to construct combinatorics expressions in Python Sympy Latex?

Tags: python, latex, combinatorics, sympy

I'm trying to construct a hypergeometric pdf equation, using the nCr expression with parentheses (n over r) using Python's sympy latex package.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks, Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `binomial`:

```
from sympy import binomial, latex
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
n, r = sympy.symbols("n, r", real=True, positive=True)
print latex(binomial(n, r) # outputs {\binom{n}{r}}
binomial(n, r)
```

This will output nCr (nicely) with parenthesis in an IPython shell or Jupyter notebook.

If you want an actual value to be evaluated, you can do:

```
from sympy import binomial, latex
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
n = 4
r = 2
binomial(n, r) # outputs 6
```

If you want the symbols 4 and 2 to be displayed, try:

```
from sympy import binomial, latex
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
n, r = sympy.symbols("4, 2", real=True, positive=True)
binomial(n, r)
```

Comment: Ah - ok, getting somewhere!  However, I don't want 'n' in the top; I'd rather have a 4, for "4 choose 2."  When I substitute the 4 in for n and 2 for r, binomial evaluates it and prints out a number.

Comment: So you'd want to display 4 nCr 2? Or you want to compute 4 nCr 2?

Comment: @user3159090 I've edited my answer to reflect your needs (I think). Let me know if it still isn't working for you, and I'll update again!!!

Comment: Works.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also use `binomial(4, 2, evaluate=False)`.

Comment: @asmeurer Nice. That's a lot cleaner than what I have as my answer.